# C#/XML: Change/Replace data from an XML file via textbox

Tags: c#, xml, save

I have a XML file which contains the following:

```
<config>
  <webservices>
     <webservice>
       <name>A</name>
       <value>http://www.123.com</value>
     </webservice>
     <proxy enabled="false" useiedefault="false">
       <name>
       </name>
       <value>
       </value>
     </proxy>
  </webservices>
</config>
```

Is there a way to change the values of 'webservice value' (from the XML file) through textbox in C# and save/update it afterwards?

```
TextBox1.Text = "http://www.abc.com";
// change value of xml
```

Comment: are you allowed to use javascript? if so then try using javascript

Answer (score 3):

I was getting a "File already opened by something else" type error.

This is your code that I modified and now it works for me:

**StreamReader fileStream = new StreamReader(filename);**

var doc = new XmlDocument();

doc.Load(**fileStream**);

var node = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"config/webservices/webservice/value");

node.InnerText = TextBox1.Text;

**fileStream.Close();**

doc.Save(fileName);

Answer (score 1):

This code fragment should work, where fileName is the full path to your XML file:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(fileName);
var node = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"config/webservices/webservice/value");
node.InnerText = TextBox1.Text;
doc.Save(fileName);
```